# Currency option not showing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

In my Magento admin panel all currency options are not showing.

I am sharing the the screenshot.

Please help me out from this problem.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in our magento admin panel.
You can see this list under Advanced->System->Currency->Installed Currencies
Find the screenshot below.

[image: Final Solution]

Thanks All :)